# Mailbox set to forward to a closed distribution group, will external email be received?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

A regular user mailbox was configured for email forwarding to a distribution group that was left configured to require authentication.

If an email from outside of the domain sender was sent to this mailbox, will it reach the distribution group members, even if the distribution group is set to require authentication?

**Tested, and emails wont deliver**

If not, than where can I recover the non delivered emails?

Thank you in advance, it is business critical to me, to find this out.

Update:

Tested and it wont deliver, so now I need to retrieve the email that where sent during this period. How can I do that?

Attached and example of the tracking log:
[image]

Comment: Hm. Why don't you try it and let us know?

Comment: I have tried and the email was not received, when the distribution group was set to require authentication, so the question remain, where could I recover the emails sent while the distro was configured closed?

Comment: These mails are gone, I think. Exchange won't save them anywhere if you don't have it set up for it. You could always add a default BCC to your own "recovery" mailbox with a transport rule to securely store them if routing fails.

Comment: What's the full error the column `RecipientStat`?

Comment: RecipientStat: 550 5.7.1 RESOLVER.RST.AuthRequired; authentication required

Comment: That's what I thought. See my other comments. Nothing you can do, I think.

Comment: Does the forwarded user mailbox still exist? Was the mailbox configured to save *and* forward, or to *only* forward messages to the DL?

Comment: It i still exists, and configured to forward only.